# merging two dataframes with different times but same dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that have same dates, same columns, but different time records within same days. I would like to merge these two dataframes so that the values within a day drop into one column with respect to their record time like below:

df1:

`datetime   temperature
2011-01-01 2:00 12
2011-01-01 4:00 12
2011-01-01 5:00 13
2011-01-01 7:00 18
2011-01-01 8:00 21
2011-01-01 10:00    21`

df2:

`datetime   temperature
2011-01-01 0:00 13
2011-01-01 3:00 11.6
2011-01-01 6:00 15
2011-01-01 9:00 20.6`

what I need:

`datetime   temperature
2011-01-01 0:00 13
2011-01-01 2:00 12
2011-01-01 3:00 11.6
2011-01-01 4:00 12
2011-01-01 5:00 13
2011-01-01 6:00 15
2011-01-01 7:00 18
2011-01-01 8:00 21
2011-01-01 9:00 20.6
2011-01-01 10:00    21`

I tried pandas.merge and pandas.appned, but the two time series did not merge properly. The second time series either follows after the first time series, or comes beside the first time series as a new column.

I would appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are looking more for `append` rather than `merge`

Comment: Try merging using merge_asof

Comment: @KevinK. 'append' does the same, just lists df2 after df1, I need to combine these two by the time of record

Comment: @Behnam The `merge` function combines (or joins) two dataframes on a column, so that the columns in each dataframe are preserved. The `append` function does as it sounds: appends the dataframe to the bottom. After you append your dataframe, you can reset the index (`df.reset_index(drop=True)`) and sort the dataframes. I suggest you read through the pandas documentation on merging and appending.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2])` and sort?

Comment: Thank you all guys! This worked fine for me:

`df= pd.append([df1,df2])` and then `df.sort_values(by=['datetime'])`